# Obter itens de uma List<String> - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, lista

Sou iniciante em desenvolvimento ASP.NET com C# e, estou com a seguinte dúvida:

Ao carregar uma página, executo um método que preenche um DropDownList.
Este DropDownList faz parte de um formulário e, após este ser preenchido e o usuário clicar no botão "Incluir", será acionado o método Incluir().

Minha intenção é obter o Index da opção selecionada do DDL pois, com base neste número, obtenho o ID que foi armazenado durante o carregamento da página em uma List

Vejam o código:

```
    List<String> _Processos = new List<String>();
    List<String> _Unidades = new List<String>();


    protected bool Incluir() 
    {
        bool r = false;

        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(cbUnidadeIncidente.SelectedIndex.ToString());

        OC o = new OC();
        o.IdUsuario = (String)Session["IDUsuario"];
        o.Dt = DateTime.Parse(txtDtOcorrencia.Text);
        o.Descricao = Kompaktor.K.KSTR(txtDescricao.Text);
        o.UnidadeIncidente = _Unidades[cbUnidadeIncidente.SelectedIndex];
        o.UnidadeAfetada = _Unidades[cbUnidadeAfetada.SelectedIndex];
        o.Observacao = txtObservacao.Text;
        o.Processo = _Processos[cbProcesso.SelectedIndex];
        o.Perda = Kompaktor.K.KSTR(txtPerda.Text);
        o.Solucao = Kompaktor.K.KSTR(txtSolucao.Text);
        o.Incluir();

        return r;
    }
```

Só que, durante a execução, justamente a primeira linha que tenta fazer o procedimento de tentar pega o Index aciona um erro, dizendo que o valor do vetor da lista foi ultrapassado.

Já sei que o problema está na List<>, afinal, usando um messagebox, o valor da selação é mostrado. Parece que as listas são zeradas ao carregarem. E agora, como posso proceder (de maneira que essas listas sejam visíveis em todo a classe) ?

Desde já, agradeço!

Comment: No seu exemplo `_Processos` está vazio. É assim mesmo que fica no momento em que `Incluir` é chamado?

Comment: Devido o Ciclo de Vida do WebForms, ele acaba por criar um novo objeto a cada requisição, por isto a sua lista não está disponível durante o Postback, Neste caso você pode colocar as listas numa Session, ViewState, Cache. Mas dependendo do caso é preferível preencher novamente a lista.

Comment: Usar MessageBox.Show em páginas web é exatamente o que não deveria acontecer. Experimente usar o SelectedValue do DropdownList.

Comment: O problema é que _Processos está vazio, você pode guardar os _Processos em uma Session ou recarregar a cada Post.

Answer (score 1):

Fiquei na duvida do seu *DropDownList* e como vc descreve ele em seu código .. "cbProcesso".. (cb) para mim é iniciais de *CheckBox* ... mas.... veja a forma que vc esta carregando o *DropDownList* e também como vc mantem os dados da sua lista.

Veja como mante uma *Session* da sua lista.

Para carregar

```
Session["_Processos"]) = _Processos;
```

para recupera

```
List<String> _Processos = Session["_Processos"]) ;
```

Uma outra forma seria vc carregar sua lista seria assim. 
Exe:

```
private List<String> m_Processos = null;
        private List<String> Processos
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_Processos == null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                         List<String> _Processos = new List<String>(){"teste1","teste2","teste3"};

                         m_Processos = _Processos;
                    }
                    catch (Exception Exc)
                    {
                        //"lErro";
                    }
                }
                return m_Processos;
            }
        }
```

e depois só chamar

```
o.Processo = Processos[cbProcesso.SelectedIndex];
```

é bom por um ponto de interrupção no seu codigo para ver o que esta passando..
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]